# 'Housekeeping' script to create folder and move files

Tags: linux, shell, perl, unix

I have been trying to investigate how to automate a script (shell or other) that periodically (once an hour for example) moves files with a constant naming convention to a folder (which is automatically created if not already there).
The files are like this:

Camera1_01_20171213221830928.jpg
Camera1_01_20171213223142881.mp4

Basically it will be doing 'housekeeping'.

I'm new to shell scripts, and I just can't work out how to create a folder if it is not there (folder called 20171213 for example), then move the relevant files into it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be able to use logrotate for this.

Comment: To create a directory if it does not exist, just do `mkdir -p 20171213`.  If the directory already exists, it's a no-op.

Comment: To periodically run the script, create a `cron` job (see `man 1 crontab` - you'll use `crontab -e`) ... don't loop and sleep within the script itself as someone suggested.  You can do a `mkdir -p /path/to/$(date +%Y%m%d)` to create the dir if it doesn't already exist (or extract the YYYYMMDD from the filename).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with a perl script which I could more easily trigger from a cron job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Copy;

main();

sub main
{
    my $dir = "/srv/NAS1/Camera1";

    opendir(my $fh, $dir) or die("Could not open '$dir' for reading: $!\n");

    my @files = readdir($fh);

    closedir($fh);

    foreach my $file(@files)
    {
        if(-d $file)
        {
            next; # skip file if its a folder
        }

        if($file =~ /Camera1_01_(\d{8})\d{9}\.(jpg|mp4)/)
        {
            my $date = $1;

            $date =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;

            my $folder = "$1-$2-$3";

            # if the directory doesn't exist
            if(!(-e -d "${dir}/${folder}"))
            {
                mkdir("${dir}/${folder}");
            }

            move("${dir}/$file","${dir}/${folder}");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if [ ! -d "$DIRNAME ]"` to see if a directory called `$DIRNAME` exists. Further you can use `mkdir` to create directories.

Alternatively, you can just use `mkdir` and ignore any error that a directory already exists. Other than that, there are no negative side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to write the script for you because you don't have enough specific information in your post, but here are the tools I think you'll need:

- [Bash](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) - Bash, for writing your script ([Here's](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) another useful reference)
- [Mkdir](https://www.unixtutorial.org/commands/mkdir/) - For making a directory if its missing (look at the -p flag).
- [Cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) - For scheduling the hourly execution of your script.
- [Sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) - For creating the new file names from the old ones

The basic code will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/joshua/photos/sort-me

for photo in $FILES/*.jpg; do
    if [[ -f photo ]]; then
        new_photo_location= #<figure this part out based on your needs>
        echo "I would move $photo to $new_photo_location"
        #mv $photo $new_photo_location
    fi
done
```

I recommend running it with that echo only until you see exactly what you like, then comment that line out and uncommont the `mv` line.

Finally, to run the script every hour on the hour, your cron entry will look something like this. (Type `crontab -e` to edit your crontab):

```
 #   Min   Hour  Day    Month   Day-of-Wk  Year  Must use absolute path
     0     *     *      *       *          *     /home/joshua/bin/sort-photos.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VDIR=$( date +%F )
VFILESFX=Camera*
[ ! -d $VDIR ] && mkdir $VDIR
while true ; do
   LTMP=$( ls $VFILESFX )
   for i in $LTMP ; do
        fuser ${i}
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && mv $i $VDIR/;
        echo "File ${i} moved to ${VDIR}";
   done
   sleep 3600
done
```

Just some explanation about this script...
The first part set the current date into a variable VDIR and the prefix Camera* into VFILESFX.
The conditional command create a directory with the value existent in VDIR if this directory does not exist, after that go to a while command interacting every hour listing all the file with the prefix setted into VFILESFX and moving this files to the directory with the current date

Comment: Are you able to tweak it to run as cronjob script rather than a loop? Thanks.